# Get data from AJAX and send them to SignalR Hub

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Good day 
I have the following code:

```
 $('#ElementId').click(function () {            
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "URL",
            data: {//DATA }
        })
                .done(function (result) {
                    FillList(result);
                });
}

    function FillList(result) 
    {
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
    chat.server.setResult(result);   
    }
```

I want to get data form AJAX call and pass them to SignalR but I just cant get it  to work. AJAX does its work but when I try to send data to SignaR Hub nothing happens.
For any help thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

Although the above doesn't work when I call the function on it own without AJAX then it works:

```
    $('#ElementId').click(function () {  
      FillList("Test");
     }
```

**UPDATE #2**
This is how the function in question looks in SIgnalR

```
public void SetResult(string TestJSON)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TestJSON))
            {
             //TODO       
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex
        }

    }
```

Comment: is the `done` callback hit after response from the server? what does the `result` hold.

Comment: Not sure about the first question but the result is a string

Comment: Are you making sure that your connection is opened before calling `setResult`? If you don't, there is no way is going to hit your hub.

Comment: @Naruto place a alert inside the done function and check if it pop's up

Comment: Yes it pops up and the data gets there but it doesn't get to SignalR function

Comment: @bsoulier I am pretty sure connection is opend otherwise what I mentioned in my update wouldn't work either. But I tried this non the less and it still doesn't work : `$.connection.hub.start().done(function () { chat.server.setResult(result); });`

Comment: Can you add your Hub code to see what you have in there?

Comment: @bsoulier  I added how the function looks in SignalR Hub but I don't see how this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible scenarios

1. `result` is `JSON` and not `string`, so make sure that you are passing a `string` to `SignalR` otherwise it will not fire:

`chat.server.setResult(JSON.stringify(result));`

2. If the above doesn't work, the problem is connectivity with your `hub`. To make sure that there is no datatype mismatch, call the server function with no parameters and see whether it's being hit:

`chat.server.setResult();`

and

`public void SetResult()`

After your **UPDATE** I'm convinced that you are passing `JSON` to your hub but it's expecting a `string`... So go with #1

Comment: It was number one I was sure it was string and didn't bother to check. Thx for help everyone